# $\ker(\alpha)=\ker(\beta) \iff \alpha\beta=\alpha$ and $\beta\alpha=\beta$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are projections and elements of $\operatorname{End}(V)$. Show that $\ker(\alpha)=\ker(\beta)$ iff $\alpha\beta=\alpha$ and $\beta\alpha=\beta$.

I know that the $\ker(\alpha)=\alpha^{-1}(0_v)$ and that $\alpha(0_v)=0_v$ for any $\alpha \in$ End(V).

Are there relevant properties for the kernel that I am missing?

Comment: You don't need any special property of kernels, just play with the fact that those operators are projections. To prove the direct assume those operators have the same kernel and try to prove that for any $v \in V T(S(v)) - T(v)=0$ (sorry, I changed the names of the operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\ker(\beta)\subseteq\ker(\alpha\beta)$, since anything sent to $0$ under $\beta$ will clearly be sent to zero under $\alpha\beta$. Hence, if $\alpha\beta = \alpha$, then $\ker(\beta)\subseteq\ker(\alpha)$, and similarly if $\beta\alpha = \beta$, then $\ker(\alpha)\subseteq\ker(\beta)$. Thus, if $\alpha\beta = \alpha$ and $\beta\alpha = \beta$, then $\ker(\beta)\subseteq\ker(\alpha)$ and $\ker(\alpha)\subseteq\ker(\beta)$, i.e. $\ker(\alpha) = \ker(\beta)$.

Conversely, suppose that $\ker(\alpha) = \ker(\beta)$. Since $\beta$ is a projection, we have $\beta^2 = \beta$, and hence $\beta(\beta-I) = 0$, where $I$ is the identity map. This implies that $\text{im}(\beta-I)\subseteq\ker(\beta)$, where $\text{im}(\beta-I)$ is the image of $\beta-I$. But $\ker(\beta) = \ker(\alpha)$ implies that $\text{im}(\beta-I)\subseteq\ker\alpha$, and hence $\alpha(\beta-I) = 0$. Thus, $\alpha\beta = \alpha$. A similar argument shows that $\beta\alpha = \beta$.

Comment: @Arthur which part of the proof are you critiquing?

Comment: Sorry, I had just woken up and read the first paragraph the wrong way.

Comment: @JoeyZou Im not following the second part. Why is the $im(\beta - I) \subseteq ker(\beta)$?

Comment: @Aksel'sRose we have $\beta(\beta(x)-x) = 0$ for any $x\in V$. Hence, if $y\in\text{im}(\beta-i)$, then $y = \beta(x)-x$ for some $x\in V$, and thus $\beta(y) = \beta(\beta(x)-x) = 0$, i.e. $y\in\ker\beta$.